# For Loop in Google Macro

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run a macro loop that copies and input, pastes it into another cell on the same sheet and then pastes the output into a cell directly next to the input. I would like the loop to continue for 135ish rows with inputs and outputs just continually getting copied and pasted.
Below is what I have so far, but when I try to run it all I get is "spreadsheet.getRange is not a function"

Update: Ive added (). to the first line and now I get a "Range not found" error

```
function SameSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet;
  for(var i = 1; i <= 132; i++ ) {
    var Team = spreadsheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    var Output = spreadsheet.getRange ( i, 2)
    spreadsheet.getRange('F1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange(Team).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    spreadsheet.getRange(Output).activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('H36:J36').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  }};
```

Comment: The first line of your code is missing (). It should be: `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();`

Comment: Start by replacing

   `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet;`

by

    `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

Comment: Regarding the loop, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices?hl=en (it's recommended whenever is possible to avoid the use of Google Apps Script methods in loops). If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
function SameSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet;
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, 132).getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
    let team = r[0];//getting same value from array is much faster
    let output = r[1];//same here
    sh.getRange(team).copyTo(sh.getRange('F1'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    sh.getRange('H36:J36').copyTo(sh.getRange(output), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  });
}
```